# Assign values based on pattern matching- Scala

Tags: scala

I have below use case, I know how pattern matching works in Scala but I have a requirement where I need to assign values based on the pattern, I wanted to avoid repeating code, Is there best way I can achieve this? Please let me know

sample value for test value will be a string with delimitor ','

```
cf match {
      case "1" => 
             val info1 => test.split(",")
             val info2 => test2.split(",")
             val info3 => test3.split(",")
             val info4 => test4.split(",")
             val info5 => test5.split(",")
      case "2" => 
             val info1 => test6.split(",")
             val info2 => test7.split(",")
             val info3 => test8.split(",")
             val info4 => test9.split(",")
             val info5 => test10.split(",")
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to do this

```
val cf = "1"
val test1 = "a,b,c"
val test2 = "d,e,f"
val test3 = "g,h,i"
val test4 = "j,k,l"

val (info1, info2, info3, info4, info5) = cf match {
         case "1" => (test1.split(","), test2.split(","), test1.split(","), test2.split(","), test1.split(","))
         case "2" => (test3.split(","), test4.split(","), test3.split(","), test4.split(","), test3.split(","))
  }

info1.toList.foreach{println}
info2.toList.foreach{println}
info3.toList.foreach{println}
info4.toList.foreach{println}
info5.toList.foreach{println}
```

this way you can reference each value individually.

Any val declaration in the pattern matching will be scoped locally to the case so technically all of those in your case will "return" unit (if those were = instead of =>)

Edit: in response to your edit. This works with any type. You can define a function that will map a tuple so you don't have to split individually

Here is a working fiddle: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Hcpmn0OsTr6RLWkUyUFVVQ
You can see it prints fine

Comment: its throwing error saying pattern type incompatible with expected type,found Array[String]  required Unit

Comment: updated the question, can you see and test it, its not working

Comment: I just tested this and it works for me. Give me a second and I will post a fiddle link

Comment: @Babu here is proof of work with integers. If you are getting type errors, it is coming from a part you didn't include or a type you didn't specify in that case please update the question accordingly https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MvkGMuqqRhWijZB95UHYkQ

Comment: @Babu You need to specify what does test values are and give some examples of their values. the error is coming from those values and we don't know what they are

Comment: Thank you ,Updated the question, please check, I think the solution works only for integers?

Comment: @Babu edited the answer with working fiddle for arrays. No this works with any type. If you are having further issues, as I have mentioned, is a result of how you are using the results of this. Please open a new question for that. It is not right to keep changing the scope of the question

Comment: sure ,Thanks. I will check on my end for whats the issue